# razor syntax, using input to run database query

Tags: c#, razor

I'm creating a simple webpage with `Razor` syntax and I have a little trouble with using buttons forms and input; how do I attach

```
db.Execute("exec dbo.deleteProject @0", @item.Key_Project);
```

to the input in last column of webgrid (via action or onclick)?

```
@{ //layout etc

var db = Database.Open("defaultConnection");
var ProjectNameGrid = new WebGrid(source: db.Query(SelectAllProjectKeysNamesStates),
canSort: false);}   

@ProjectNameGrid.GetHtml(
        columns: ProjectNameGrid.Columns(
            ProjectNameGrid.Column("Key_Project", "ID", style: "smallColumn"),
            ProjectNameGrid.Column("ProjectName", "Project", style: "LongColumn"),
            ProjectNameGrid.Column("ProjectStartDate", "Starting date"),
            ProjectNameGrid.Column("ProjectEndDate", "Ending date"),
            ProjectNameGrid.Column("IsActive", "Active", style: "smallColumn"),
            ProjectNameGrid.Column("Key_Project", "", format: 
            @<input type="submit" method="post" action="" value="delete" />) ),
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt")
```

Answer (score 0):

use Razor ActionLink Like Bellow:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", "Controller", new {param1 = val1, param2 = val2}, null)
```

Comment: Error: HtmlHelper does not contain definition for ActionLink ...
Can I do something like     
`  
if (IsPost && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Request.Form["addNewProjectName"] != null)
        {
            db.Execute("exec dbo.AddNewProject @0", Name);
        }
        else if (Request.Form["addNewTask"] != null)
        {
            if (TaskName != "")
            {
                db.Execute("exec dbo.AddNewTask @0, @1, @2, @3", TaskName, ProjectID, isDailyTask, DailyTaskGoal);
            }
        }
    }
`

Comment: use like bellow:
`grid.Column(columnName: "Text", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.ColumnName), "ActionName", new { id = item.id })),`

Comment: i would prefer to use only (isPost...) and omit ActionLink

Comment: i did make 
`ProjectNameGrid.Column("Key_Project", "", format: @<form action="" method="post"><input name="deleteProject @item.Key_Project" type="submit" class="submit" value="delete" /></form>
`

Comment: and then
`if (IsPost && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        List<int> ProjectIDs = new List<int>();
        foreach (var row in db.Query("SELECT Key_Project FROM DimProject"))
        {
            var deleteProjectName = "deleteProject " + row.Key_Project;
            if (Request.Form[deleteProjectName] != null)
            {
                db.Execute("Exec deleteProject @0", row.Key_Project);
            }
        }
}`

Comment: No this is wrong in mvc pattern. Perhaps you work on Web from in paste. You must use html helper and action post in controller.ok

Comment: Why you don't use ORM like EF for data layer? It's simple.

Comment: i dont know whats ORM and EF and i dont follow MVC for webpage for home only use

Comment: also you can use grid.mvc Extension in: [link](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) this is simple